# Find values into Array of Object PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Hi I have this array of object

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "categories": [
      222,
      243,
      208,
      115,
      173,
      253,
      236,
      121,
      69,
      250,
      221,
      270,
      245,
      123,
      124
    ]
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "categories": [
      222,
      243,
      208,
      69,
      250,
      221,
      270,
      245,
      123,
      124
    ]
},{
    "id": 8774,
    "categories": [
      222,
      243,
      208,
      115,
      173,
      253,
      236,
      121
    ]
}
]
```

I want to search in the "categories" array of all objects values in other array and print the match.

Example, I want search the values `222` and `121`, values that I push in array

```
$array = ("222","121");
```

And I want search this two values in the result, and print only the object id = 1 and 8774 because are the ones that coincides.

I tested with array_filter into a foreach but doenst works! Any idea? Thanks

This my code

```
    $search = array("231","228");
    $result = array_filter($array, function ($item) use ($search) {
        if (array_intersect($item["categories"], $search)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
//$array is the array of object result
```

Array_intersect works but I need print only the Objects that contains the values into a "search" array. Considering that the "search" array can have more than two values

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

Comment: `array_filter` should work. Show your code so we can tell you what you did wrong.

Comment: Edited @Barmar. Array filter works but array_intersect that I have not work for me but I want the objects that contains the values in search array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_intersect($array1, $array2)` will be truthy if there are any matches between the two arrays. It looks like you only want to select the items that have *all* the categories in `$search`. To test that, you need to use

```
if (count(array_intersect($item["categories"], $search)) == count($search))
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/FMKsOY)

Also, in general there's no point in writing

```
if (condition) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Just write:

```
return condition;
```

So it looks like:

```
$result = array_filter($array, function ($item) use ($search) {
    return count(array_intersect($item["categories"], $search)) == count($search);
});
```